# How do I stop my gif from freezing in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, gif, freeze, photoimage

I'm trying to use Python 2.7 and Tkinker to play a gif on loop. It is to be run on a raspberry pi, but my implementation is lagging even on my more powerful Macbook pro. Here is an example of how it's implemented:

```
frames= [] #holds gif images
weatherIND = 0 #frame of gif currently being displayed


#processes and initializes gif, then starts the loop 
def getWeather() 
   global frames

   frames= []
   self.processImage("assets/Rain.gif")
   print("frames len = " + str(len(frames)))

   Photo = frames[0] #initialize 

   self.iconLbl.config(image=Photo)
   self.iconLbl.image = Photo
   self.after(0, self.update) #start the loop

#displays the next frame of the gif every 20 ms 
def update(self):
    global weatherInd
    global frames

    if weatherInd == (len(frames)):
        weatherInd = 0
    Photo = frames[weatherInd]

    self.iconLbl.config(image=Photo)
    self.iconLbl.image = Photo

    weatherInd+=1

    self.after(20, self.update)


#takes a gif and puts each frame in a list as a PhotoImage object
def processImage(self, path):
    '''
    Iterate the GIF, extracting each frame.
    '''
    global frames

    mode = 'global'

    im = Image.open(path)

    i = 0
    p = im.getpalette()
    last_frame = im.convert('RGBA')

    try:
        while True:
            print "saving %s (%s) frame %d, %s %s" % (path, mode, i, im.size, im.tile)

            '''
            If the GIF uses local colour tables, each frame will have its own palette.
            If not, we need to apply the global palette to the new frame.
            '''
            if not im.getpalette():
                im.putpalette(p)

            new_frame = Image.new('RGBA', im.size)

            '''
            Is this file a "partial"-mode GIF where frames update a region of a different size to the entire image?
            If so, we need to construct the new frame by pasting it on top of the preceding frames.
            '''
            if mode == 'partial':
                new_frame.paste(last_frame)

            new_frame.paste(im, (0,0), im.convert('RGBA'))


            new_frame = new_frame.resize((100,100), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            Photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(new_frame)
            frames.append(Photo)

            i += 1
            last_frame = new_frame
            im.seek(im.tell() + 1)
    except EOFError:
        pass
```

Now the problem is that when the gif is playing, every 5-10 seconds it will hang on a frame for 1/2-1 second. This would be expected if I were trying to process or resize the gif frame every 20 ms, but I believe I'm just updating the label with a pre-processed image. Is there a more efficient way to do this so tkinter won't lag?

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import os


root = Tk()

frameCnt = 175
frames = [PhotoImage(file='C:\\Users\\qadi_\\Downloads\\download.gif',format = 'gif -index %i' %(i)) for i in range(frameCnt)]

def update(ind):

    frame = frames[ind]
    ind += 1
    if ind == frameCnt:
        ind = 0
    label.configure(image=frame)
    root.after(15, update, ind)
label = Label(root, borderwidth=0)
label.place(relx = 0.5,
                   rely = 0.5,
                   anchor = 'center')


root["bg"] = "black"
root.attributes("-fullscreen",True)
root.after(0, update, 0)
root.mainloop()
```